# Eliminar campos repetidos sql

Tags: sql-server

Alguien podría darme una mano con mi código?

```
select nro_viaje 
into #vviajes
from [ARROSWKS604\SQLEXPRESS].[Test].[dbo].[Hoja1$]

select nro_viaje, cod_cliente
into #cclientes
from [ARROSWKS604\SQLEXPRESS].[Test].[dbo].[Hoja1$]

Select distinct ST2.cod_cliente,
substring(
    (
        Select '-'+convert(varchar,ST1.cod_cliente)  AS [text()]
        From #cclientes ST1
        Where ST1.nro_viaje = ST2.nro_viaje
        ORDER BY ST1.cod_cliente
        For XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 1000) COMBINABLES
,(SELECT count(*) FROM #vviajes TMP2 WHERE ST2.nro_viaje = TMP2.nro_viaje GROUP BY nro_viaje)
From #cclientes ST2
```

La primer columna mostraría todos los "cod_cliente". Lo que intento hacer es mostrar cada uno de los "cod_cliente" que realizaron un mismo viaje llamado "nro_viaje", pero sin que el "cod_cliente" se repita en el campo COMBINABLES.

Éste es el resultado que obtengo:[image: RESULTADO]

Como les mencione, se repite el valor de la columna "cod_cliente" en COMBINABLES, que es lo que no quiero que aparezca.

Cualquier ayuda sirve!

Comment: porque no pruebas con el `distinct` igual que en el `select` principal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dificil de probar sin tener la tabla, pero probaste con Distinct (cambiando el text por nvarchar) o gruop By?. Hay que cambiar el tipo de dato de Text a Nvarchar porque con Text no se puede hacer ni Distinct, ni Group By.

**Distinct**

```
select nro_viaje 
into #vviajes
from [ARROSWKS604\SQLEXPRESS].[Test].[dbo].[Hoja1$]

select nro_viaje, cod_cliente
into #cclientes
from [ARROSWKS604\SQLEXPRESS].[Test].[dbo].[Hoja1$]

Select distinct ST2.cod_cliente,
substring(
    (
        Select distinct  '-'+convert(varchar,ST1.cod_cliente)  AS [nvarchar(max)]
        From #cclientes ST1
        Where ST1.nro_viaje = ST2.nro_viaje

        ORDER BY ST1.cod_cliente
        For XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 1000) COMBINABLES
,(SELECT count(*) FROM #vviajes TMP2 WHERE ST2.nro_viaje = TMP2.nro_viaje GROUP BY nro_viaje)
From #cclientes ST2
```

**Group BY**

```
select nro_viaje 
into #vviajes
from [ARROSWKS604\SQLEXPRESS].[Test].[dbo].[Hoja1$]

select nro_viaje, cod_cliente
into #cclientes
from [ARROSWKS604\SQLEXPRESS].[Test].[dbo].[Hoja1$]

Select distinct ST2.cod_cliente,
substring(
    (
        Select '-'+convert(varchar,ST1.cod_cliente)  AS [nvarchar(max)]
        From #cclientes ST1
        Where ST1.nro_viaje = ST2.nro_viaje
        GROUP BY '-'+convert(varchar,ST1.cod_cliente)
        ORDER BY ST1.cod_cliente
        For XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 1000) COMBINABLES
,(SELECT count(*) FROM #vviajes TMP2 WHERE ST2.nro_viaje = TMP2.nro_viaje GROUP BY nro_viaje)
From #cclientes ST2
```